Vuetify2 styles not working properly with Django
I'm trying to add vue + vuex + vuetify framework to my django project
I have installed node.js and yarn, then prescribed the commands - yarn global add @vue/cli and vue create client in project root dir,  and modified the config files:

package.json

{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service build --dest=../../static/builds/dev --mode=development --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-modal-dialogs": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuetify": "2.6.5",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}


main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')


vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'
import ru from 'vuetify/es5/locale/ru'
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  lang: {
    locales: {ru},
    current: 'ru'
  }
});


then I ran the yarn dev command and plugged the assembled files into the existing html from static
    <script defer="defer" src="{% static 'builds/dev/js/app.js'%}"></script>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="structure-tab-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="structure-tab">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>

But vuetify is not built correctly, the tags work, but the styles don't, no matter what I do
example how it should be
as you can see there is no icons and no styles
tried everything from this thread vuetify icon not showing but nothing works

Although you mentioned having tried everything in that thread, the posted code does not actually include the material-design-icons.

@huanfeng yeah, i deleted this import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' lines they didn't do anything for me anyway.

Which package did you install? If you have installed material-design-icons-iconfont
You should add below styles in main.js:
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';

If you import @mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css as from your comments:
You should install package: @mdi/font
Both of these lines are importing CSS files for Material Design Icons, but from different packages.

ok, guess this fixed mdi icons (i also added parameter icons: {     iconfont: 'mdi',   } to export default new Vuetify ), but standart vuetify styles still missing
